# How to .find() multiple documents containing mistakenly renamed fields to $elemMatch

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

i think this is a simple question so here we go:

i have for example this product inside my products collections:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("623e0a15eaf77143a9e03a9a"),
    title: 'Product 1',
    variacoes: { '$elemMatch': { quantidade: 1 } },

  }
]
```

i want to do a simple .find() on all the documents that have this pattern showed in the field `variacoes` how can i do this?

i tried so many things now that is a shame here are some of the pearls if it helps in the process of solving my question

```
db.produtos.find({variacoes: {$elemMatch: {'$elemMatch': { $elemMatch: { quantidade:1 } } } } } )

db.produtos.find({variacoes: {'$elemMatch': {$elemMatch: {quantidade:1}}}})

db.produtos.find(   { variacoes: { $elemMatch: { $elemMatch: { $elemMatch: { quantidade: 1 } } } } }   

db.produtos.find({variacoes: {$elemMatch: {$elemMatch: {quantidade: {$gte: 0}}}}})
```

none of them work

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
db.collection.find({
  "variacoes.$elemMatch.quantidade": {$exists: true}
})
```

You can see it works [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VnzBFv5lxpG).

On mongoDb, in order to get nested object you need to use `.` not `{`.